# Iv'e tried defining a function in ruby with constant parameter names, why does it throw an error?

Tags: ruby, syntax, parameters, constants

whenever I try doing `def foo(CONST1, CONST2)`..., it always gives an error, even if only the function name is a constant.

```rb
# Error!
def foo (BAR, BAZ)
   puts BAR + BAZ
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby is an unusually case-sensitive language so you can't do certain things because capital letters have syntactical meaning. Other languages don't care, but Ruby does.

For example your method arguments *must* be variables. You cannot define constants here. Capital letters at the beginning indicate a constant, no exceptions.

You should define this as:

```
def foo(const1, const2)
  # ..
end
```

Some rules:

- Method names, variables and arguments are `lower_case`.
- Classes and modules follow `ClassName` and `ModuleName` respectively. These are technically constants.
- Other constants are defined as `CONSTANT_NAME`

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by defining "constant parameter names", so if you could explain maybe there's a better answer here.

Comment: Yes, the error is, "formal argument cannot be a constant", but you have not explained why arguments are not permitted to be constants. I assume it is because the constant lookup may be unsuccessful, depending on scope, but you probably can explain it better than I.

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "constant parameter name". If you want a constant, define a constant. Parameters (method arguments) are for things that change, that's why they're there. If this method is within a module or class, that's where you put the constant.

Comment: true, but they don't have to change inside the function

Comment: You're sort of right in that they take up less memory. It's mostly that a constant is declared once and once only, it persists for the lifespan of the process, so they *can* be more memory efficient. They can also be less efficient because they stick around forever, so it's not without tradeoffs. It really depends on what kind of a constant you're declaring, and the cost of retaining it.

Comment: An unchanging argument is not the same as a constant. In Ruby there's no equivalent to C++ `const` arguments for example, it's up to the caller to lock down any values supplied, like with `freeze`.

Comment: Raphael, why do you not want to simply reference a constant defined outside your method? Note that you cannot define or change a constant within a method either, as *dynamic constant definitions* are not permitted.

Comment: I want it to have the advantage of a, constant, taking less memory, since the parameters don't have to change inside the function, but since parameters of a function are the same variables, they just change when you call it the function again. :-(

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and probably premature optimization. Unless you're having *measurable* memory problems, don't stress about this. Do the simplest thing that works, and if you have problems you can measure, fix those.

Comment: Not really, there are lot of times where memory and speed matters in programming, I just first encountered that in a specific case.

Comment: Given that computers today are really fast and have tons of memory, the number of times is actually fairly small. Ruby isn't especially memory efficient or fast, it's just very easy to work with, so you've already made some trade-offs just using Ruby.

Comment: they're very fast with very _small_ programs, but I realized that recursion and loops slow it down, _a lot_.

Comment: The number one thing you can do to speed up code is to pick the correct algorithm. The second thing is to implement it efficiently in whatever language you've chosen. The third is to port to a different language if you *must*.